# Animate scrollTop with offset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jQuery UI accordion but some of the text is too long which causes it to be neaer the top of the page. What i wanted was when a section was opened it would jump to the top of the section. This code works perfectly in doing that but it snaps to the top, which looks clitchy.

```
$('#accordion').bind('click',function(){
theOffset = $(this).offset();
$(window).scrollTop(theOffset.top - 50);
});
```

How would i animate the scrollTop so it "glides" to the top

Many thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use

```
$('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: theOffset.top - 50
});
```

instead of

```
$(window).scrollTop(theOffset.top - 50);
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept this answer by clicking the check to the left if it helped you. Thanks. :)

Comment: quite fast answered +1 from my side.

Answer (score 0):

use [jquery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to *animate* the properties over specified time instead of just applying them instantly.

```
$('#accordion').bind('click',function(){
    theOffset = $(this).offset();
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: theOffset.top - 50;
    });
});
```